# can anyone please help me understand this query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Can anyone help me understand this query? The `mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefId.mktgPgm` part mostly. Generally it is `table_name.columnName` but here the format seems to be different

```
SELECT mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.mktgpgm, 
       mktpgm.mktgpgm, 
       mktpgmvhclxref.cmpgn, 
       campaign.cmpgndescription, 
       mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.vhcl, 
       vhclhierarchy.modname, 
       mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.modyr, 
       mktpgmvhclxref.userinsrt, 
       mktpgmvhclxref.rowinsrt 
FROM   mktpgmvhclxref mktpgmvhclxref, 
       mktpgm mktpgm, 
       vhclhierarchy vhclHierarchy, 
       campaign campaign 
WHERE  mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.mktgpgm = mktpgm.idmktgpgm 
       AND mktpgmvhclxref.cmpgn = campaign.campaignid 
       AND mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.vhcl = vhclhierarchy.vhcl
```

Comment: are these `mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefId` the actual table and schema names?  please tell me they are not real.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, it shouldn't work, because the table/alias is not in the FROM clause. Unless `mktpgmvhclxrefId` is a special type with a `vhcl` member.

Comment: the db,table and col names must be randomly generated i guess :)

Comment: @bluefeet Possibly a (very ugly) shorthand for "marketing program VHCL cross-reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the anwer to my question .
its related to hibernate mapping.
The second field is actually for composite key of a table .

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you add some more information to understand this answer?

Comment: At the time of ORM in hibernate if the given table gets data from more than one table and primary key cant be just a single column den two columns together make a composite key. And a pirticular column is represented as tableName.compositeID.columnName

Comment: But that's not SQL, then. That's HQL, I guess?

Comment: No worries. Just be sure that you always give as much information as possible on Stack Overflow, next time... E.g. the fact that you're using Hibernate is very relevant to this question

Answer (score 4):

Often, the first identifier is the schema / database name, depending on your database:

```
[schema].[table].[column]
```

In most databases, `[schema]` and `[table]` qualifiers are optional, if the `[column]` name is unambiguous.

In your case, however, I doubt that this is the actual case as `mktpgmvhclxref` is a table in your `FROM` clause. Oracle for instance, also knows user-defined types (UDTs, `OBJECT` types). So I'm guessing that:

```
mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefid.mktgpgm
```

Corresponds to

```
mktpgmvhclxref   = table
mktpgmvhclxrefid = column
mktgpgm          = UDT attribute
```

If you're using Oracle, you can probably find your UDT as such:

```
select * 
from all_type_attrs 
where (owner, type_name) = ((
  select data_type_owner, data_type
  from all_tab_cols
  where table_name = 'MKTPGMVHCLXREF'
  and column_name = 'MKTPGMVHCLXREFID'
))
order by attr_no
```

Comment: Are you sure ? because others seem to follow the tableName.columnName pattern and secondly i checked out that the table name here is mktpgmvhclxref which according to the pattern you said should be the schema name

Comment: @user1643087: Yes, see the updated answer. In your case, I think that your dereferencing a UDT attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
mktpgmvhclxref.mktpgmvhclxrefId.mktgPgm
[--Schema----].[----table-----].[Column]
```